# jQuery - setInterval doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to code a little Homepage with jQuery. It has a form and I want to check something with jQuery.

I have a textbox with the id `points`.
jQuery has following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    if ($("#points").value().length > 500) {
      alert("Too many points!");
    }}, 100)
});
```

But it doesn't work. Can someone help me?

Comment: `.length` checks the length of the string, not the actual value of the input.

Comment: you need to expand on _"doesnt work"_ what exactly isnt working? I would guess though its that you are trying to use `.value()` which isnt a valid native function of a jquery object maybe use [.val](http://api.jquery.com/val)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. There is no function called `value()` in jQuery. It's `val()`. For JavaScript, It is `.value`.
2. You are trying to get the `length` of the number, which will give you `3` if the number was `123`.

   ```
   $(document).ready(function() {
     setInterval(function() {
       if ($("#points").val() > 500) {
         alert("Too many points!");
       }
     }, 100);
   });
   ```

Comment: There are supposed to be two curly braces. One closes the if, one the function.

Comment: Oops! my bad. Didn't see that.

Comment: Yeah, it was val() but i thought value() works too, but it was the same problem.

But thanks, it worked :)

Comment: @Aarivex - No worries! :)